# ACE Editor Autocomplete tooltip

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tooltip, ace-editor

I'm actually trying to use the ACE Editor Autocomplete function.
I have added custom functions (and objects) to my script and I want to display them in my autocompletion.
I could display use the "caption", "value" and "meta" property. But I did not very well understand how the "score" work precisely.

And (the objective of this post) I would like to know how to display a tooltip (like the ones pre-registred).

For your information, I am using Lua mode and I need custom autocomplete, because I am using proxy objects for Moonsharp.

Thank's and best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add getDocTooltip method to your completer similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.8/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L73

Comment: Thanks, could not find this in documentation.